# Funciones DOM e innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un código para mostrar por pantalla diversa información pero éste me falla. También debo utilizar `innerHTML` creando un nodo.

El código es el siguiente:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var info = document.getElementById("informacion");

  // Numero de enlaces de la pagina
  var enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName("a");


  // Direccion del penultimo enlace
  var mensaje = "El penultimo enlace apunta a: " + enlaces[enlaces.length].href


  // Numero de enlaces del tercer párrafo
  var parrafos = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  enlaces = parrafos[2].getElementsByTagName("a");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ejercicio 17</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <h1>DOM</h1>
  <h2>Crear mapas</h2>
  <p>Cree mapas interactivos que expliquen sus datos y animen a los usuarios a explorarlos. Cree un mapa de sus propios datos y gane perspectiva agregando los datos acreditados basados en ubicación incluidos en ArcGIS Online. Utilice la representación cartográfica
    inteligente para guiar la exploración y la visualización de los datos.
    <a href="https://www.esri.com/es-es/arcgis/products/arcgis-online/capabilities/make-maps">Información sobre creación de mapas</a>
  </p>

  <h2>Herramientas para desarrolladores</h2>
  <p>Todas las capacidades de ArcGIS Online están disponibles a través de diversas API y SDK. Los desarrolladores pueden empezar su trabajo aprovechando los mapas, análisis y estilos creados por sus compañeros del ámbito de la representación cartográfica.
    Amplíe y personalice elementos de ArcGIS Online y desarrolle aplicaciones personalizadas con las herramientas de desarrollador.
    <a href="https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-for-developers/overview">Explorar ArcGIS for Developers</a>
  </p>

  <h2>Operaciones de campo</h2>
  <p id="third-paragraph">Conecte operaciones de campo y oficina con datos compartidos. Cree datos, mapas y aplicaciones para su referencia o uso por parte del personal de campo para fines de captura de datos. Utilice <a href="https://doc.arcgis.com/es/collector/android/create-maps/offline-map-prep.htm">mapas sin conexión</a>    y sincronice cuando vuelva a conectarse. Los datos capturados pasan a formar parte de ArcGIS Online para utilizarlos en aplicaciones y cuadros de mando.
    <a href="https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/field-operations/overview">Explorar operaciones de campo</a>
  </p>

  <p>
    <a href="https://geonet.esri.com/welcome">Geonet</a> es el lugar donde puedes compartir, chatear y colaborar con todo tipo de recursos geo.
  </p>

  <p>
    <a href="http://mappingcenter.esri.com">Mapping Center</a> es el sitio destinado a ayudar a crear mapas con ArcGIS.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Estoy un poco encallado en este punto. No sé como continuar. Entiendo que la solución debe ser sencilla pero ahora no encuentro ninguna.

Comment: agrega tu html, que nodo necesitas crear? donde? agrega mas detalles a tu pregunta

Comment: Buen día, podrías decirnos que es lo que quieres lograr con tu código? qué problemas tienes? cual es lo que te falla?... danos más detalles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falla por varias razones.

Estás tratando de obtener un elemento con id **informacion** el cual no existe. Para el ejemplo lo creé al final.

En la pregunta mencionas que debes crear un nodo, o lo que es lo mismo, un nuevo elemento `HTML`. También te dejé un ejemplo agregando un `span` en el párrafo nuevo.

*Revisa el snippet en pantalla completa para que veas el ejemplo con el nuevo párrafo al final.*

Los demás hallazgos los dejé comentados en el código. Si tienes dudas adicionales, deja un comentario.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //Capturar el elemento con id informacion (último párrafo)
  var info = document.getElementById("informacion");
  //Mostrar en consola el contenido del párrafo
  console.log(info.innerHTML);
  //Crear un nuevo nodo, en este caso un span
  var nodo = "<span style='color: red;'> Crear un span dentro del párrafo con id <b>informacion</b></span>"
  //Agregar el nuevo nodo al último párrafo
  info.innerHTML += nodo;

  // Numero de enlaces de la pagina
  var enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  console.log("Cantidad de enlaces: " + enlaces.length);

  //El penúltimo debe ser length - 2 ya que los array inician en cero y length inicia en 1
  var penultimo = (enlaces.length - 2);
  
  // Direccion del penúltimo enlace
  var mensaje = "El penultimo enlace apunta a: " + enlaces[penultimo].href;
  console.log(mensaje);

  // Numero de enlaces del tercer párrafo
  //Obtener los párrafos
  var parrafos = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  //Obtener los enlaces del párrafo 3 que en el array viene siendo la posición 2
  var cantidadEnlaces = parrafos[2].getElementsByTagName("a");
  console.log("La cantidad de enlaces del terecer párrafo es: " + cantidadEnlaces.length);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ejercicio 17</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <h1>DOM</h1>
  <h2>Crear mapas</h2>
  <p>Cree mapas interactivos que expliquen sus datos y animen a los usuarios a explorarlos. Cree un mapa de sus propios datos y gane perspectiva agregando los datos acreditados basados en ubicación incluidos en ArcGIS Online. Utilice la representación cartográfica
    inteligente para guiar la exploración y la visualización de los datos.
    <a href="https://www.esri.com/es-es/arcgis/products/arcgis-online/capabilities/make-maps">Información sobre creación de mapas</a>
  </p>

  <h2>Herramientas para desarrolladores</h2>
  <p>Todas las capacidades de ArcGIS Online están disponibles a través de diversas API y SDK. Los desarrolladores pueden empezar su trabajo aprovechando los mapas, análisis y estilos creados por sus compañeros del ámbito de la representación cartográfica.
    Amplíe y personalice elementos de ArcGIS Online y desarrolle aplicaciones personalizadas con las herramientas de desarrollador.
    <a href="https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-for-developers/overview">Explorar ArcGIS for Developers</a>
  </p>

  <h2>Operaciones de campo</h2>
  <p id="third-paragraph">Conecte operaciones de campo y oficina con datos compartidos. Cree datos, mapas y aplicaciones para su referencia o uso por parte del personal de campo para fines de captura de datos. Utilice <a href="https://doc.arcgis.com/es/collector/android/create-maps/offline-map-prep.htm">mapas sin conexión</a>    y sincronice cuando vuelva a conectarse. Los datos capturados pasan a formar parte de ArcGIS Online para utilizarlos en aplicaciones y cuadros de mando.
    <a href="https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/field-operations/overview">Explorar operaciones de campo</a>
  </p>

  <p>
    <a href="https://geonet.esri.com/welcome">Geonet</a> es el lugar donde puedes compartir, chatear y colaborar con todo tipo de recursos geo.
  </p>

  <p>
    <a href="http://mappingcenter.esri.com">Mapping Center</a> es el sitio destinado a ayudar a crear mapas con ArcGIS.
  </p>
  <p id="informacion">Mostrar este texto en consola</p>
</body>

</html>
```